# In Civilization 6 how to keep mobile SAM on a "stay alert" mode?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization 6, late game unit mobile SAM has only two modes - "skip turn" and "sleep". There is no stay alert mode. And in each turn clicking on the "skip turn" of all the mobile SAM's is a very cumbersome task. So if I click on "sleep" will they automatically wake up during an air raid? If not how to keep mobile SAM on "stay" alert" mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anti-air units in Civ 6 are always considered active and will attempt to shoot down enemy air units attacking targets within their range without requiring an action. This applies whether they have spent their movement points, skipped their turn, or are "sleeping".

Another option, if you find moving your AA support units is time-consuming, is to put them in an escort formation with your regular troops.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the Mobile SAM is a support unit and not a "regular" unit with which you can attack. Its bonus is, therefore, inherently, passive like that of a UAV or Supply Convoy. Its function is as the solution described.

Comment: ^ Their typical use is sleeping on a city to reduce/prevent city damage, or alongside other units to support against air strikes on your individual troops